# Intercept HTTP requests in server java

Tags: java, web-services, http, jax-ws, interceptor

I need to implemented something like a filter or listener, that intercepts HTTP requests and retrieves the HTTP headers for various purposes.

I use Java, Jboss application server and web services. I want this filtering system to be performed prior to the Web Services call - was thinking about aspects but they do not hold the HTTP related stuff. After the filter, the service call should be carried out.

Jax-WS handlers don't work for me either as they only hold the SOAP payload.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you not create a servlet filter which intercepts all the requests coming to your webservice engine? If you are using Axis or anyother SOAP engine, I hope you should be able to create a filter that intercepts all the requests coming to the main servlet that the SOAP engine provides.

```
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response,FilterChain chain) throws IOException,ServletException
  {
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest=(HttpServletRequest)request;
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse=(HttpServletResponse)response;
       Enumeration headerNames = httpRequest.getHeaderNames();
        while(headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
          String headerName = (String)headerNames.nextElement();
          out.println(headerName);
          out.println(request.getHeader(headerName));
        }
       chain.doFilter(request,response);
}
```

Comment: As far as I am aware, the filter interface just provides with the ServeletRequest and ServletResponse, which do not contain HTTP related information. Edited: I would need the HttpServletRequest object instead. Am I missing something here maybe?

Comment: Almost everything you need should be there.. Check out the sample code here.

Comment: More on here http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeaderNames()

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Isn't the getHeaderNames() method part of the HttpServletRequest interface? As I said, that's not the object type passed in the filter's "doFilter()" method :/

Comment: You can downcast ServletRequest to HttpServletRequest inside doFilter. See the code with more changes as appropriate.

Comment: @Pascal: If the requests are going to be HTTP requests it should be safe to cast the `ServletRequest` and `ServletResponse` arguments to `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse`.

Comment: Make sense to me now. Thanks ColinD and Shamik :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) and the Java interface [jNetPcap](http://jnetpcap.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Had taken a look and looks very much like a low level API. I just need to extract the HTTP headers. Does it allow chaining of the interceptors with further components like a web service?