# SOAP and REST requests intercepting

Tags: xml, json, rest, soap, intercept

Is it possible to intercept binding of XML/JSON data coming through SOAP or REST webservice, to modify/check some of the data ?

let's say I have methods like this on my webservice:

@WebMethod
public SomeDTO someMethod(@WebParam(name = "duh" SomeDTO someDto) {...}

And whenever XML/JSON is being bind to SomeDTO i would like to check if the value has some specific words in it, or something like that. Is this even possible ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intercept HTTP requests in server java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816285/intercept-http-requests-in-server-java)